# How do I get a specific error from g_poll?

Tags: c, glib

The g_poll() function returns `-1` *"on error or if the call was interrupted"*. (See: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-poll).

If `g_poll` returns `-1` how do I determine if this was because the call was interrupted vs. if there was an error?

If it was an error, how do I determine the cause of the error? Is it sufficient to look at `errno`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Check **`errno`** if `g_poll()` returns `-1`. The documentation also says

> **gpoll()** polls fds, as with the poll() system call, but portably.
>   On systems that don't have poll(), it is emulated using select().

i.e. `g_poll()` uses **`poll()`** and **`select()`** internally.
Hence, check the various scenarios that `errno` is set to various values by [**`poll()`**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) and [**`select()`**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)